# Show Total Row In Grid Each Time Name Changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am attempting to display a grid on my page and each time the name in the grid changes display a Total for that name.  However, I keep getting a error of `Object not set to instance of an object`  This is my syntax I am trying, can someone take a look and fill me in on what I am doing wrong?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" OnDataBound = "gvODB" OnRowCreated = "gvORC" >
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="userID"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="employeename" HeaderText="Name"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="hoursworked" HeaderText="Daily Hours"></asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>


private int currentId = 0;
private decimal subTotal = 0;
private decimal total = 0;
private int subTotalRowIndex = 0;

protected void gvORC(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  subTotal = 0;
  try
  {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        dt = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).DataView.Table;
        int userID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["userID"]);
        total += Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["hoursworked"]);
        if (userID != currentId)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowIndex > 0)
            {
                for (int i = subTotalRowIndex; i < e.Row.RowIndex; i++)
                {
                    subTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(gvTest.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text);
                }
                this.AddTotalRow("Total", subTotal.ToString("N2"));
                subTotalRowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
            }
            currentId = userID;
        }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
    throw exception;
  }
}
protected void AddTotalRow(string labelText, string value)
{
  GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);
  row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F9F9F9");
  row.Cells.AddRange(new TableCell[3] { new TableCell (), //Empty Cell
                            new TableCell { Text = labelText,     HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right}, 
                            new TableCell { Text = value, HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right } });

    gvTest.Controls[0].Controls.Add(row);

}
```

EDIT --
The grid will return a userid, username and hours worked.  And I want a total to be displayed for each individual username returned.  Something like so
userid    name    hours
1646      Red     16
1646      Red     8
Total             24
1812      Blue    6
1812      Blue    8
Total             14

Now a userid, name and hours will ALWAYS be returned, the only time a null value would be returned is when all results have been added to the grid.

Comment: Nobody can write a good answer with the information you provided, but speaking in general terms, your Exception is almost certainly one or more of the places you access an item by index then access a property without doing any null checking. Also, are you aware of Footer templates?

Comment: The question lacks the context for me to know exactly what "each time the name in the grid changes" means. Maybe footer template is not appropriate here. To null check you simply test `if (x == null)`. So for instance, check if gvTest is null, then test if gvTest.Rows is null then test if gvTest.Rows[I] is null then test if gvTest.Rows[I].Cells is null, etc, etc.

Comment: @Crowcoder - see my edit, does that help clarify?

Comment: if the grid is read only this would be much more easily accomplished with some kind of repeater control or even a report.

Comment: @Crowcoder - how would I use a repeater control to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to generate the html that will display your simple "report". There are any number of ways to do this. If the data is read only then using a Grid is less appropriate than just building a `table` or set of divs, etc. You can look into the Repeater or ListView but here I demonstrate a simple `table` element:

The aspx markup that has a simple asp:Table with runat server:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<asp:Table runat="server" ID="usertbl" border="1">

</asp:Table>

</asp:Content>
```

The Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Contrived Data table just because I need some data to demonstrate.
            //I assume you are or can acquire a DataTable with your current solution.
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserID", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserName", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Hours", typeof(int)));

            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row[0] = 1646;
            row[1] = "Red";
            row[2] = 16;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row[0] = 1646;
            row[1] = "Red";
            row[2] = 8;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row[0] = 1812;
            row[1] = "Blue";
            row[2] = 6;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            row = dt.NewRow();
            row[0] = 1812;
            row[1] = "Blue";
            row[2] = 14;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            //Simplify accumualtor logic by grouping on Userid
            var users = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(u => u[0]);

            //For each group (each user id)
            foreach (var item in users)
            {
                //adds the user hours
                int accumulator = 0;

                //For each set or rows in group
                foreach (var dr in item)
                {
                    accumulator += int.Parse(dr[2].ToString());

                    //Create a table row
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow();

                    //Add the cells to the table row
                    TableCell userIdCell = new TableCell();
                    userIdCell.Text = item.Key.ToString();
                    tr.Cells.Add(userIdCell);

                    TableCell userNameCell = new TableCell();
                    userNameCell.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                    tr.Cells.Add(userNameCell);

                    TableCell hoursCell = new TableCell();
                    hoursCell.Text = dr[2].ToString();
                    tr.Cells.Add(hoursCell);

                    //Add the row to the table
                    usertbl.Rows.Add(tr);
                }

                //create summary row
                TableRow totalRow = new TableRow();
                //Skip a cells
                totalRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                totalRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                //total cell
                TableCell userTotalCell = new TableCell();
                userTotalCell.Text = accumulator.ToString();
                totalRow.Cells.Add(userTotalCell);

                //Finally add the row
                usertbl.Rows.Add(totalRow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the result:
[image]

Comment: oh that looks perfect!!  Is their a way I can add the word "Total" to the actual total rows?  If not, it is okay, but visually that would be nice.  And yes, the data is read only.

Comment: Yes, you can add "Total" or anything you want in one of those empty cells.